# How to make a fancy mysql join that can join three tables and detect if one table DOESNT have my item

Tags: php, mysql, join

php mysql query 
I have multiple linked tables - I also have a table that only creates and entry if certian conditions exist so I would like to add that into my query to avoid having to go through thousands of query searches looking for this special case

here is my current query

```
$query = "SELECT a.UUID FROM contract a 
        INNER JOIN geoPoint b ON a.customer_UUID = b.customerUUID
        WHERE b.garcom_UUID = '$garbCom'
        AND b.city_UUID = '$city'";
```

I then go through each item that was returned (in the thousands)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $sentdata = getothertable($row['UUID']); //checks if the item is in the table
             $sent = $sentdata ['senttoGarcom'];
             if($sent == 0) //if it wasn't found add it to my list
    {
       array_push($Contracts,$row['UUID']);
    }
    }
```

instead of all that I would like to just make it one query - pseduo code something like this

```
 $query = "SELECT a.UUID FROM contract a 
            INNER JOIN geoPoint b ON a.customer_UUID = b.customerUUID
            INNER JOIN contract_sales c ON a.UUID = c.contractUUID
            WHERE b.garcom_UUID = '$garbCom'
            AND b.city_UUID = '$city' AND c.DOESNOTEXIST";
```

this way I dont have to return thousands I will only be returned the few that are not yet in the contract_sales table and I can go about my business...

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What are the table structures like and how are they related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check for `NULL` rows of c with a `outer join`

```
$query = "SELECT a.UUID FROM contract a 
        INNER JOIN geoPoint b ON a.customer_UUID = b.customerUUID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN contract_sales c ON a.UUID = c.contractUUID
        WHERE b.garcom_UUID = '$garbCom'
        AND b.city_UUID = '$city' AND c.contractUUID IS NULL ";
```

Comment: Works perfectly and much less than the other solutions Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a left outer join problem

Have a look at this example. You specifically need to have a check for a null in a column in the table which you want to find the missing row rof

[mysql left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058834/mysql-left-outer-join)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery is what you need:

```
$query = "SELECT a.UUID FROM contract a 
            INNER JOIN geoPoint b ON a.customer_UUID = b.customerUUID
            WHERE b.garcom_UUID = '$garbCom'
            AND b.city_UUID = '$city' 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM contract_sales c
                              WHERE c.contractUUID = a.UUID)";
```